# Deploy Safe to Avalanche Subnet (Custom EVM)

Tags: evm, gnosis-safe, avalanche

We have an Avalanche Subnet, and are looking to deploy Safe.

I understand the process for opening a request to have the singleton factory deployed (However unsure if this is supported on Avalanche? `subnet-evm`).
Also unclear the UI, as it relies on Infura which a custom EVM chain does not support (I'm confident we could deploy the infrastructure service)

Non-tech people will need to have access to our Safe, so we're aiming to deploy the UI to make it as user friendly as possible. I understand there is a third party CLI that we can use, however not ideal.

Thanks in advance!